# MYSQL UPDATE SELECT from Two Tables

Tags: mysql

U[sing the selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644389/mysql-table-update-from-other-table), I attempted to craft a MySQL query that select columns and set values but am getting a 'Every derived table must have its own alias'.  I only have two tables: matrix_swfl_res & RLN which I've defined as e & d respectively.  What am I missing?

```
UPDATE (SELECT e.MLSNumber, d.MLSNumber
          FROM matrix_swfl_res e, RLN d
         WHERE e.MLSNumber = d.MLSNumber)
   SET e.RSLN = d.RSLN
```

Comment: You didn't read the answer you are linking ?

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes indicative of poor design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the answer linked, you have to do a Join when you want to update a table

Here the mysql error is because

```
(SELECT e.MLSNumber, d.MLSNumber
          FROM matrix_swfl_res e, RLN d
         WHERE e.MLSNumber = d.MLSNumber)
```

is considerated as a derivated table, as you write it, it's like you want to update this derivated table.

If I understand what you want :
You want to update the table A with some select you have done previously, here is what you need to do :

```
UPDATE A 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT e.MLSNumber, d.RSLN
              FROM matrix_swfl_res e
                   INNER JOIN RLN d ON e.MLSNumber = d.MLSNumber ) as Q 
    ON A.MLSNumber= Q.MLSNumber)
SET A.RSLN = Q.RSLN
```

I don't have all the tables details, but I hope with this example it will be clearer

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your linked answer is what you need - something like

```
UPDATE matrix_swfl_res e
   INNER JOIN RLN d ON e.MLSNumber = d.MLSNumber
   SET e.RSLN = d.RSLN
```